# Python ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.7

First of all, no question I found on the internet helped me solve this. So, I have this structure:

```
.
└── Python Scripts
    ├── Functii.py
    └── Generator Siruri
         └── GeneratorSiruri.py
```

I have another directory inside Python Scripts aside from Generator Siruri, and a few extra .txt files that I use in GeneratorSiruri.py but I didn't include them since I find them irrelevant. Inside GeneratorSiruri.py I want to import a function from Functii.py, which is in the previous directory. The first line I use to import said function is:

```
 from Functii import citeste_fisier
```

where citeste_fisier is the name of the function. In fact I tried importing everything from my custom functions module, since they are so few, but nothing works. I tried every variation of the import statement. Some of these are:

```
 - from .. Functii import citeste_fisier
 - import Functii
 - from Functii import *
```

and many other variations of it. What is more interesting is that a classmate replicated my structure and the import worked fine for him. And yes, I know I could make a package with __init__.py but it should work without it as well, and I prefer to not change the structure if it should work the way I wanted initially.

Comment: Not a "clean" solution but you can add the "Python Scripts" directory (preferably as absolute path) to the `sys.path` list so that it is used as root directory for script searching. After that, `from Functii import citeste_fisier` and `import Functii` should work.

Comment: @MichaelButscher It is something that I will try, thanks. But I still hope to find out what the real problem is, finding workarounds does not mean the problem is gone and it's bugging me.

Comment: When you do `import Foo` in Python, every directory in the `sys.path` list is searched, in order, for a package or module of that name. So you have to make sure the directory your module is in is on `sys.path` (the current working directory is usually the first path entry by default). You can add additional `PATH` entries using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: That said, once you get that working, I strongly suggest looking up how to create a `setup.py` for your module and installing it in a standard way using `pip`. This will be more robust long term. If you're `import`-ing a module it isn't really a "script" per se, but more likely a library that should be installed to the standard location for third-party libraries.

Comment: Well, after creating PYTHONPATH and adding my folder into the PYTHONPATH it still didn't work. However, I found it weird that I couldn't type python in my console and enter the interactive console, instead I had to write "py". So after reading how to solve that problem, I added Python3.7 both in Path and PYTHONPATH, afterwards I could write python in console AND my import statement worked.